# Factorization of $x^7-1$ into irreducible factors over $GF(4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I need to find cyclotomic cosets depending on $n=7$ and $q=4$ and find the factorization of $x^7-1$ into irreducible factors over $GF(4)$.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Well, 1 is a root, so that's a start.

Comment: So I have $(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$.

Comment: Moreover, $x^7-1$ splits completely over $\mathbb{F}_8$, since its factorization in $\mathbb{F}_2$ is $(1+x)(1+x+x^3)(1+x^2+x^3)$. Note that there is no irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with degree $2$ that divides $x^7-1$.

Answer (score 2):

As has been noted by Jack D'Aurizio in his comment, the polynomial $x^{7}-1$ splits into a product of $x-1$ and two different irreducible factors of degree $3$ over $F_{2}.$ This certainly gives the same factorization (but not a priori into irreducible factors) over $F_{4}.$ However $F_{4}$ and $F_{16}$ contain no element of multiplicative order $7,$ so contain no root of $x^{7}-1$ other than $1,$ so the two factors of degree $3$ remain irreducible in $F_{4}[x].$